# Convert string to function

Tags: common-lisp

I have the string "+" and I want to convert this into #'+.
Basically I want to map string to the corresponding function
i.e. "myfunname" to #'myfunname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly an XY problem: why are you starting with strings?

If you *do* need to turn strings into functions then something like the below will do that and is significantly safer than using `read`:

```
(defun string->function (name &key (readtable-case (readtable-case *readtable*))
                              (package *package*))
  (let ((effective-name (map 'string
                             (ecase readtable-case
                               ((:upcase)
                                #'char-upcase)
                               ((:downcase)
                                #'char-downcase)
                               ((:preserve)
                                #'identity)
                               ((:invert)
                                (lambda (c)
                                  (cond
                                   ((upper-case-p c)
                                    (char-downcase c))
                                   ((lower-case-p c)
                                    (char-upcase c))
                                   (t c)))))
                             name)))
    (multiple-value-bind (s status) (find-symbol effective-name package)
      (unless status
        (error "no symbol for ~S (from ~S)" effective-name name))
      (unless (fboundp s)
        (error "no function for ~S (from ~S, originally ~S)" s effective-name name))
      (symbol-function s))))
```

Now

```
> (string->function "+")
#<Function + 80E004F189>

> (eql (string->function "+") #'+)
t

> (string->function "string->function")
#<Function string->function 80200011E9>

> (string->function "unknown")

Error: no symbol for "UNKNOWN" (from "unknown")

> (string->function "*print-case*")

Error: no function for *print-case* (from "*PRINT-CASE*", originally "*print-case*")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I can learn a lot from your answer. To give background: I get textfiles with instructions like a = b + c and a = b * c. These instructions I want to turn into functions.

Answer (score 2):

If the set of possible functions is limited and known, then you can search for the symbol in a list.  Symbols are string designators for their name, so you can compare with `string=`.

```lisp
(find string '(+ - *) :test #'string=)
```

You can use `funcall` directly with a symbol, so no further translation is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you say:

> To give background: I get textfiles with instructions like a = b + c and a = b * c. These instructions I want to turn into functions.

You want to have a parser and some kind of interpreter that explicitly but indirectly associates the language you are implementing (equations) to the language of your implementation (Common Lisp).

You may have a good result with a hack that uses the Lisp reader, but this is just a coincidence that `+` exist in both languages; what if the `+` in your language is not exactly the same function as `#'+` in CL? (maybe you are adding vectors or matrices, etc).

First of all you would need to read your input as an abstract-syntax tree:

```
a = b + c
```

Would be:

```
(assign a (add b c))
```

I'm purposefully not using `+` here to avoid confusion.

There are good resources out there to implement this step. Feel free to ask additional questions.

Then you would write an `evaluation` function to interpret that exactly as you want; maybe:

```
(evaluation '(add b c) env)
```

is exactly equal to:

```
(cl:+ (evaluation 'b env) 
      (evaluation 'c env))
```

So you would have to write a rule like this somewhere for `add`, and for any other operation that exist in your language.

Comment: Yes this is an issue I faced. For a different project I wanted to write lisp objects to file and later on read them again (although in that case there should be a standard way to go forward). I suppose this also goes in the direction of domain specific languages? I can not totally follow your argument as I am not familiar with abstract syntax trees I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

As @Svante said:

```
(funcall (read-from-string "+") 1 2 3)
;;=> 6
```

You want usually get the function to apply it.

You can also use `apply` - with just the difference to `funcall` that all the arguments must be packed into one list for `apply`.

Both, `funcall` and `apply` search for the function already if you give the symbol. You can get symbol from string by `read-from-string`.

```
(apply (read-from-string "+") '(1 2 3))
;;=> 6
```

As @ignisvolens said it is an XY problem (you think something is the problem but actually something different is the problem).

You want to parse strings. Then you need `apply`.